# How to create spirals along all edges for complex objects?

Tags: modeling

Lets say I have a cube (or any mesh). How can I create spirals along all of its edges? (connected too at the vertices if possible) I've seen other solutions before that involve adding curves, but I need this for more complex objects.
Essentially I'm trying to model a complex bendable shape that I'm going to 3d print, and creating spirals manually along all the paths and joining them seems very difficult to do without some sort of a plugin.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this https://youtu.be/a59r5inndX4 . Do you know you can convert mesh to curves and curves to meshes?  What have you tried?  It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.
I make 3D models using Blender and 3D print them on a Prusa

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://imgur.com/zyLIUN0